# JavaScript; How to require special naming of files

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, filenames

I'm trying to validate through JavaScript that the uploaded files have special filenames. I want my files to have this structure; EN1234567890.wav. This means that the first two characters of the filename should be letters, and the last 10 characters should be digits. The extension doesn't matter as I have a different validator for that. The filename, without the extension should always be of 12 characters.

This is the script I have;

```
var filename = fullfilepath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');

if (!filename.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z\.]*$/)) {
    alert('File name should only containg letters and numbers, please rename image file and upload.');
}
```

This script will only check for just letters and numbers in the filename, but not after my "own" structure. How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use repetition markers:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{10,10}/
```

http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=93635

Comment: So what's wrong with this line of code? I'm trying to check a filename uploaded through a form;

if(data.files[0]['name'] != (/[a-zA-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{10,10}){ alert("Wrong filename."); return; } @Plato

Comment: @zorensen first you're missing the trailing `/` marking the regex, secondly you can't just test equality against the regex. use `...['name'].match(regex)`

Comment: Like this? It doesn't work... if(data.files[0]['name'].match(/[a-zA-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{10,10}/)) { alert("Wrong filename."); return; }

Comment: Figured it out. I did like this. Works like a charm!
  if (!data.files[0]['name'].match(/[a-zA-Z]{2,2}[0-9]{10,10}/)) {
   alert("Wrong filename");
   return;
  }